# Sign up and login directly with Devise in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sign up mechanism which completes after link to activation through confirmable. now i want to remove confirmable and i want user to directly login after the sign up. please tell me what changes i need to do and how can i do this? do i also need to remove confirmation fields from db? please tell me the whole procedue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `@user.skip_confirmation!` before saving user in db.
If you are using registration_controller then the @user object will be resource like.

This is registrations_controller create method.

```
def create
    build_resource
    resource.skip_confirmation!
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => inactive_reason(resource) if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
```

Comment: It works but i dont want to change in the controller of registeration because im not freezing the devise gem, is there any other way so that i can remove the confirmable from within my application????

Comment: other possible solution is: u can remove confirmable from user.rb model. then drop db - create db- then migrate and c whether ur code works or not...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the confirmable module from the User model.

```
devise :confirmable, …
```

Comment: well i have did this but its not working, even now my sign up page is not signing up.....